# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: logging, log4j, appender, rollingfileappender

I have a log file currently configured to roll over every hour. When it is first created it is called logfile.log, and once it rolls over it is renamed to logfile.log.YYYY-MM-DD-HH.

What I would like is for the log file to be created immediately using the logfile.log.YYYY-MM-DD-HH naming convention as opposed to logfile.log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post:

- http://tecbites.blogspot.com/2006/10/log4j-tipps-and-tricks.html

It discusses the use of DatedFileAppender described here:

- http://minaret.biz/tips/datedFileAppender.html

I never used this one, but it seems to be doing exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks I ended up writing my own appender similar to this one.